# How do I print out only the first 3 elements of an array that has 5 elements in java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, element

How do I only print out the first 5 elements of an array that has 10 elements?

I know I can just do:

```
String[] strArray = {"bacon", "chicken", "ham", "egg", "poop"};
System.out.println(strArray[0]);
System.out.println(strArray[1]);
System.out.println(strArray[2]);
```

But assuming I had 100 elements and wanted to print out the first 25 elements. Or wanted to print out all elements from the 10th to the 50th. Writing all the lines of code would take up time.

Is there like a way to tell the console to print "from" one element to another? Sort of like from 10-50? So like a short-cut.

Comment: Hint: [*for-loop*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Comment: read about loops. for loop is your friend. java.util.Arrays.sort() is good to sort arrays and it is your friend as well. =]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Print first 25 elements:

```
for (int i=0; i<25; i++) {
    System.out.println(strArray[i]);
}
```

Print element number 10 to 50:

```
for (int j=9; j<50; j++) {
    System.out.println(strArray[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very easily using a for loop

```
String[] strArray = {"bacon", "chicken", "ham", "egg", "poop"};
for (i = 0; i < 3; i ++){
    Ssytem.out.println(strArray[i]);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

**Since Java 8**

You can use `limit` from the `Stream` class:

```
Stream.of(strArray).limit(3).forEach(System.out::println);
```

or

```
Arrays.stream(strArray).limit(3).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is very basics, but just giving a reference code so that you can write a generic method like this one, which takes string array and start and end index from where you need to print , and checking if your starting is not less than 0 or ending greater than size of the array itself..

```
    public void printElements(String[] strArray,int start , int end)
        {
        if(start > 0 && end <strArray.length)
           for (int i=start; i<end; i++) 
            {
            System.out.println(strArray[i]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a function like that:

```
public void print(String [] array, int range1, int range2){
     for(int i = range1, i < range2, i++)
          System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

You can add some if controls for range1 and range2 values. For example these values can't be lower than zero or higher than array.length

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple to print elements of array. Let's take a function `printElemnts()` to demonstrate how to print elements of array.

```
public void printElements(String [] array, int startingIndex, int lastIndex) {
    for (int i = startingIndex; i < lastIndex; i++)
        System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

In your case you can set the `startingIndex` as zero and `lastIndex` as some value.